# How can add some values into beginBody() Yii2?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

How can I add `oncopy="return false;"` into html `<body>` in Yii2

`body` is initialized with the help of `$this->beginBody()`, how to add some values in?

in the end it should be `<body oncopy="return false;">`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to add any relevant html/php whatsoever. That makes it easier for people to help you

Comment: I solved this problem simply by adding tags with text to a specific class

Comment: Please consider posting the solution as an answer to your own question, so people who come here in the future having the same problem can still profit. Thanks